# Observation about Polynomials Addition

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, polynomials, irreducible-polynomials

For two polynomials $f_1=(x-a)(x-b), f_2=(x-a)(x-e)$, if we add them together: $f_3=f_1+f_2$, $f_3$ only has an integer root that is $a$. I observed that it'd possible to make $f_3$ have more than one integer root, for example if I do: $f'_3=f_1+c\cdot f_2$, where $c$ is a constant value. Please note that this is true just for some $c$ but not all constant values. I also observed that if we multiply $ f_1 $ and $ f_2 $ by two different polynomials, $f'_1, f'_2$ of the same degree (e.g. degree 2) as $f_1$, such that $f'_1, f'_2$ have no roots in common, we wont have this problem. Therefore, $f''_3=f'_1\cdot f_1 + c\cdot f'_2 \cdot f_2$ has only one integer root that is $a$.

**Hence, we cannot find a constant value $c$ to make $f''_3$ have more than one integer root.**

My question: 1- Is the above observation correct. 2- If so, how I can prove its correctness ? 3- Would the above observation be true for higher degree polynomials $f_1$ and $f_2$, where $\deg(f_1),\deg(f_2)> 2$

Comment: $(x-a)(x-b)+(x-a)(x-e)=(x-a)(2x-(b+e))$ and $f_1+f_2$ has an integer solution $x=(b+e)/2$ given $b+e$ is even. Also, given $f_1$ and $f_2$ have already a common solution, multiplying them by some non zero polynomial will never result in two new polynomials with no roots in common

Comment: @user160738 many thanks for the answer, the first bit was so useful, but for the last part of your answer, I'd say I don't want the result have "more than one" integer root. Thus I need $f''_3$ to have only $a$ and nothing more.